# hg bitbucket "does not appear to be a largefile store"

Tags: windows, mercurial, push, abort

Has anyone already got the error message during hg push on Windows 7 ?

```
"abort: hg [my bitbucket repo] does not appear to be a largefile store"
```

I had this message when trying to push a few files which are a few kB only. Our repo doesn't have largefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitbucket doesn't have [large file support](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/3843/largefiles-support-bb-3903)

The error string "does not appear to be a largefile store" comes from the hg largefiles extension, so its likely that you have it enabled.

If you repo uses the largefile extension, not necessarily containing files large in size, then you won't be able to push your repo to bitbucket. Look for a .hglf folder in the root directory of your repo. If its present then you are using the largefiles extension.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419442/how-to-remove-largefiles-from-mercurial-repo) for help in removing large files.